# Получение изображения JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Я в JavaScript не силен, но необходимо к нему прибегнуть. Задача весьма не стандартная. Имеется приблизительно такой html:

```
<img src='http://server.com/?image=RANDOM_STRING' />
```

Изображение генерируется разное. Я могу добавить к этому тегу атрибуты. Мне нужно получать это изображение и передавать посредством браузера, т.е через JS. С отправкой проблем не возникает, только вот с получением ничего не могу сделать.
Возможно этот пост чем-то поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: передавать откуда куда?

Comment: Получение изображения идет с одного хоста, а отправляться должен на мой. Понимаю что обычно такие вещи делаются с других ЯП, но другого варианта, увы, нет.

Comment: а почему просто ссылку не отправить на сервер - в чем смысл само изображение качать?

Comment: Изображения каждый раз разное.. Альтернативных вариантов нет, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пользоваться новинками `XMLHttpRequest` (ранее известными как *XHR Level 2*), чтобы [получать и отправлять **бинарные данные** (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data). *Поддержка браузерами [довольно неплоха](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2).*

Если с данными не нужно ничего делать, проще всего оперировать `Blob`ами.

Получение:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var blob = oReq.response;
  // можно использовать blob где-то ещё
};

oReq.send();
```

Отправка:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  // отправка завершена
};

oReq.send(blob);
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Однако проблема, на сайте используется аунтефикация, а без нее к изображению не достучаться. С самого тега img никак нельзя вытянуть изображение?

Comment: @FilippMustang не вижу, чем это мешает. Запрос же делается через текущую сессию браузера.